# How get get a java -jar <jarfile> running with Java 11?

Tags: java, java-11

I understand that Java 11 does not provide a JRE anymore, but I need to be able to run some java apps via commandline using the classic  syntax

```
java -jar <jarfile>
```

What do I need to install and/or configure to get this working again?
When I now - after having uninstalled Java 8 (JDK and JRE) and subsequently installing Java 11 (JDK only) and execute the above commandline all I get is:

```
Error: opening registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\JRE'
Error: could not find java.dll
Error: Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment.
```

How do I set up a Java 11 environment under Windows 10 such that it allows me to run apps on the command line?

Comment: Java 11 supports `java -jar`. Looks like your environment is broken. Can you execute `java -version`?

Comment: Not sure where you got the idea that Java 11 lacks a JRE - that would somewhat defeat the purpose of Java 11...

Comment: Voting to close, not helpful to future readers. Has nothing to do with jars, its just a broken Java installation.

Comment: @Zabuza yes - it's a broken installation but apparently it gets broken using the normal uninstall old version / install new version procedure. So IMHO it is and remains a valid question.

Comment: @Boris the Spider: Re. your remark "... where you got the idea that Java 11 lacks a JRE": Just go to Oracle's Java 11 download page or google for "Java 11 lacks JRE" and start reading...

Comment: I would say there are places on the internet that claim that the Java 11 JDK doesn't have a JRE, which leads to this kind of confusion.

For myself, this question was quite helpful in realizing that a problem I thought I was having with Java 13 was actually a problem with own setup, and it led me to the solution. In my view, that makes this a useful question.

Answer (score 2):

@ZhekaKozlov - you are right! Thanks!
There was some leftover in my PATH setting, namely an entry `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath` pointing to a non-existing directory `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\<somenumber>`.
Removing that entry from the PATH and double checking that JAVA_HOME points to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2` and PATH contains an entry `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` got me going!

Now I get:

```
C:\Users\mmo>java -version
java version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9-LTS, mixed mode)

C:\Users\mmo>
```

Comment: You must have made made that change yourself; so that makes this question very specfic to your own setup.

Comment: No - I did not! This C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath setup and it's addition into the system's path variable was the standard way how prior JRE installations registered themselves in Windows. I would never have come up with such a weird setup...

Comment: I too had this in my PATH through no action of my own. I presume @mmo is correct that it was the standard part of old JRE installs in Windows. For some reason the Java uninstaller from Oracle did not clean this up for me, but manually editing my user-space environment variables cleaned it up easy enough. (Thanks for providing a good, conventional example of how to add the JDK's binaries to PATH! That saved me some time, too.)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add the bin path of the java 11 to the system variables. 
Go to Control Panel > System > Advanced System settings.
Under Advanced click on Environment Variables.
Now under the section System variables search for Path and click edit. 
Add the Path to the JDK 11's bin folder, it should looks something like this:
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2\bin
and move it up in case you have some other jdks or jre installed. 
Done, now you are able to use Java commands on the commandline.